# Why do I see my TV in my Network locations, and how?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, tv

Today I've noticed that there is my TV showing in my Network locations.

[image]

It looks like a shared network device and contains folders like `Current Channel`, `Watch Satellite`and `Watch TV`. Unfortunately, these folders are either empty or have VIDEO files that are not playable.

Can someone please explain how and why this happens? What is the name of this tech?

Comment: Do you have Device Discovery enabled? You can [edit] to include the required information necessary to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, you have enabled Network Discovery in
*Network and Sharing Center > Change advanced sharing settings > Private >
Network discovery*.

On the other hand, you have a smart television that is connected to the
same local network (router) as your PC and that acts as a media device.

Windows discovers the device on the network and sees whatever
network shares that it chose to share with the network (normally not
very useful).

This means that you can cast your PC screen or a media file to the TV,
for example by using Chrome's *3-point menu > Cast*.
The possibilities depend on the capabilities of the TV's firmware.

For more information see the article
[How to cast your Windows desktop to a smart TV without a cable, and mirror your desktop display onto your TV](https://www.businessinsider.fr/us/how-to-cast-windows-desktop-to-tv).